# How is the way to write 3D Web Application for Custom Tailoring?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, 3d

As I research in web, I found simulation application for custom tailoring website can be written in some way. I have some knowledge about JavaScript, HTML5, CSS3 and PHP programming. But I still don't know how to write [simulation program like this](http://www.tailor4less.com/en/men/custom-dress-shirts/configure). Can somebody share me your ideas how do I prepare to write application like that?

Even I research a couple of week, it's my poorness I can't even understand step by step development process of the application. [Here is the sample application made by Tailor 4 less](http://www.tailor4less.com/en/men/custom-dress-shirts/configure).

I have no ideas for application like this too [Here is application made by Tailor Store UK](http://www.tailorstore.com/tailor-made-shirts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tailor application you gave a link you uses quite low-tech approach. It uses (pre?)generated images for each option (using transparency layer). Images are stacked one upon another to produce the final result.

Of course, the end-result is looking nice, which is due to careful web-design.

In short: you need a pile of carefully prepared images (it's a lot of routine work unless you have them readily 3d-modelled) for each detail and clever URL-mapping to choose the image. Everything else is just programming choices in HTML/javascript and loading correct images into corresponding layers.

Use browser's development tools (like Firebug for Firefox) to discover how the application works.

Comment: I really thanks for your idea. I also trace by using firebug for how it is work. Only now I can confirm by your idea.

Comment: How about application like this http://www.tailorstore.com/tailor-made-shirts ? Is that the same techniques as we seen before? @Roman

Comment: Yes, the technique is the same.